# Нужно помощь как из ссылки https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/ сделать ссылку https://yadi.sk/i/

Tags: python

```
import yadisk

y = yadisk.YaDisk(token="Токен")


print(y.get_download_link('Tags.txt'))
```

Показывается ссылка `https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/814f44bb37ceadaa2f4a6ff1a9fc03b90f14032b48449dbc897c38cd01eb3f47/61daf739/UtwJ1kAuXgyzjB8ixwChKsrRCyAR_as6PnDrHxdyMTZJeaY-mpGtPOiZaVNoIsJdJX9auNyfdOVmCkDt8ZGmBA%3D%3D?uid=1510442267&filename=Tags.txt&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=text%2Fplain&owner_uid=1510442267&fsize=457&hid=eb574d9bc80551b8050033def758413a&media_type=document&tknv=v2&etag=6f2e9d85cbe6148d04dad419540b0aa9`
Как мне ее преобразовать в  `https://yadi.sk/i/`

Comment: может это сделать нельзя ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как через библиотеку yadisk создать ссылку на скачивание?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369939/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-yadisk-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)